# Python string capture

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have the below sample paragraph:

```
Some paragraph contents 
email address: 1234532@aol.com
seq_id : 1234567
```

The `seq_id` line may contain the below possible patterns. There will always be `:` with prefix of 
`seq`, `SEQ`, `seq_id`, `SEQ_ID`, etc., and I just need the digits after the `:` 
which is `1234567`, but not the email id which may have the same or different digits.

```
seq id:1234567
seq_id : 1234567
seq_iD : 1234567
seq_iD:1234567
seq_ID: 1234567
```

So far I tried to store this as a list and was checking if a word is a digit but that's returning true for email Id data as well.

Sometimes I get `id:1234567` as a word which makes it not get detected as a digit.

Is there any better way to get this done?

Comment: _So far I tried to store this as List and was checking if a word is digit but that's returning true for email Id data as well. some time I got "id:1234567" as word and which is giving me this is not digit._ Please share the actual code, as well as the current output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a regular expression.

```
import re
s = "some string or data input, in this case your paragraph" 
re.match('seq(?:[_\s]id\s?):\s?(\d+)', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE).group(1)
```

This ignores case, then looks for optinal spacing just about everywhere and puts all the digits into a group which is returned by `group(1)`

You can test the regex and [see it work interactively](https://regex101.com/r/aW3pR4/25):

[image]

## Update to handle missing spaces per request:

For example: `Seq Id:1234567` doesn't work with the regular expression above.

Change the regex to: `seq(?:[_?\s?]id\s?):\s?(\d+)`

Comment: Thank you. For this input "Seq Id:1234567" is not working - there is no space between ":"

Comment: @user8781522 add two question marks like so: `seq(?:[_?\s?]id\s?):\s?(\d+)`. That makes the whitespace and underscore both optional. Mark as answered or upvote? Trying to build rep on the site

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re
para = "seq id:1234567 seq_id : 1234567 seq_iD : 1234567 seq_iD:1234567 seq_ID: 1234567"
r = re.compile("[sS][eE][qQ](?:[_\s][iI][dD]\s?):\s?(\d+)")
r.findall(para)
```